# PHP - Password RegEx requirements

Tags: php, regex, passwords, alphanumeric

I am trying to validate if a new user account's password is matching these criterias:

- Between 8-30 characters long
- Contains at least 1 lowercase letter (a-z)
- Contains at least 1 uppercase letter (A-Z)
- Contains at least 1 of the following special characters: _-!#*@&

I have a function like this:

```
function validPassword($str) {
    return preg_match("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_-!#*@&])[A-Za-z\d_-!#*@&]{8,30}$", $str);
}
```

But I am getting an error. It should return "true" for this password for example: `HelloWorld123!`

But instead it is returning false. Any idea what may be wrong?

```
if (validPassword($password) == true) {
  // good password
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use delimiters for the pattern.

Comment: Could you show me an example of what delimiter you're talking about? And where exactly should it be placed?

Comment: The hyphens in the character class should be at the start/end or escaped as well `return preg_match("~^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-_!#*@&])[A-Za-z\d_!#*@&_]{8,30}$~", $str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape '-', and delimiters...

```php
function validPassword($str) {
  return preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_\-!#*@&])[A-Za-z\d_\-!#*@&]{8,30}$/", $str);
}
```

Comment: I did not know I had to escape that because it's inside [ ]?

Comment: @TibiaCams '-' is range character.
Now, just mark an answer you like as accepted and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is having errors which is why there is no match in the first place.

**Change your regex to this:**

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_\-!#*@&])[A-Za-z\d_\-!#*@&]{8,30}$
```

Have a look at your regex in action here: https://regex101.com/r/ogPPeb/1